# Python: Functions in Control Structures

Tags: python

I was wondering why I do not get any output from the function when doing something like this:

```
def x():
  print 'hi'
  a = True
  return a

b = False

if (x and (b == False)):
  print 'some string'
```

Is the

> print 'hi'

statement actually executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `print 'hi'` statement is not executed. You need to **call** the function for it to run:

```
if (x() and (b == False)):
```

Note the `x()`, the parenthesis invoke (call) the function.

The above can be better expressed as:

```
if x() and not b:
```

Python functions are first-class objects; `x` is just a reference to the function object, and does not invoke it. Function objects, like most objects in Python, are considered `True` in a boolean context:

```
>>> def foo(): return False
...
>>> foo()
False
>>> bool(foo)
True
```

so even if you had changed `a` to be `False` in your function (so `a = False`) your code would *still* have printed `some string`.

Comment: @user2697260: You forgot to include them in your original code too; if you *had* included them, you would have seen `Hi` printed.

Comment: I get your point, but this was just a small test in the interpreter... in my actual source code I invoke the function correctly.

Comment: @user2697260: Then show us the actual function; something *else* is wrong.

Comment: @user2697260: Your code as posted here, with `x()` corrected, works just fine.

Comment: I have not executed it, this was just a general question.